# Restart key command for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any **key command** to **Restart** android studio

Or can we create a **key-map** for android studio to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a restart AS key binding available. You can bind quit, but not restart. Why would you need to restart AS so frequently?

To hotkey quit, you go

File > Settings > Keymap and then search for "exit"

Answer (score 0):

There is no a **Key Command** to restart Android Studio (AS). However if you question, is related to the inconsistency behavior on AS you can use **Caching and Invalidate mechanism**. This is very useful to clear and restart the AS when overlapping old files in memory. See details about *Cleaning System Cache* on link [Cleaning System Cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html?origin=old_help).

You can find the *Cleaning System Cache* from AS menu `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`